# Stepping through a file after pattern match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to acquire the first and last name fields from a file between blocks of text. I have tried PHP, awk, and Perl but can't get exactly what I want.

The Data:

```
[ABC-001]
first=firstabc001
phone=sometext
last=sometext

[DEF-001]
phone=sometext
last=sometext
first=firstdef001

[ABC-002]
phone=sometext
first=firstabc002
last=sometext

[GHI-001]
first=firstghi001
phone=sometext
last=sometext
```

Function call: get_firstname( $W=ABC, $N=002 )

Search and return: firstabc002

---

I am trying to create a PHP site that grabs the first name from the values I send it as the values are stored in a flat file.

I don't necessarily care which language does this as long as I can call it from PHP ( which shouldn't be a problem ).

I have tried PHP, awk and Perl but couldn't get this to work.

---

I just need it to return the value. I am not sure if the flat file should be read in as one big string, an array, or loop through and get each line and then step through after I reached the [ABC-002] header, etc.

I have tried online regex utilities as well for php preg_match and I cant get array[n] to show the fisrtabc002 results

---

Thanks to those who submitted an answer for the help. I didn't know about parse_ini_(file|string) http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

I will mark the best answer in a little bit when I do some further testing.

I do like the perl and awk options as I have had need for those functions at different times and now they are in my bag of tricks.

Comment: Please show the PHP or Perl code that you're having problems with

Comment: "I am trying to create a PHP site that grabs the first name..." Then you should be looking for a PHP solution, not a Perl, awk, or sed solution.

Comment: I agree a php solution but I am asking for help with any kind because I can call an external program to get the result I want. I am trying to appeal to the masses.

Comment: As for my PHP or Perl code, I have scratched most of it as I am just pissing in the wind and randomly trying things.

Comment: SO is not a "give me the code" kind of girl.

Comment: Post the desired output.

Comment: Jay - I am sorry you see it that way. Not asking for the code. Looking for help. Your comments are not helping just as you see me not being a contributor. You might as well not comment then. Thanks though!

Comment: Pedro, the desired output is listed in the question : Search and return: firstabc002

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Please rephrase it to something like: "I have this" and "I need this". Also post a demo of  "the file".

Comment: There is no `ABC-002` header...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - true. corrected it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [parse_ini](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) you can code something like:

```
function get_firstname( $w, $n ){
    $ini_array = parse_ini_file("test.ini", true);
    if($ini_array["$w-$n"] AND $ini_array["$w-$n"]["first"]){
        return "First Name:" . $ini_array["$w-$n"]["first"];
    }else{
        return "Not Found";
    }
}

echo get_firstname("ABC","002");
//First Name:firstabc002
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse it...

```
$sections = parse_ini_string($iniString, true);
foreach($sections as $section) {
    echo "{$section['first']}\n";
}
```

If you want the `first` item in the `ABC-102` section then:

```
$sections = parse_ini_string($initString, true);
foreach($sections as $header => $section) {
    if ($header === 'ABC-102') {
        echo $section['first'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldnt get it with string but I have it working with parse_ini_file and now I need to put it in a function wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Provided, I got you right and you are searching for the firstname that ends in $N in the section that starts with $W, I'd do it in perl like this:

Update: according to the comments above you search for the section that starts with $W and ends in $N, i.e. `[$W-$N]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# set input record separator to an empty line:
$/ = "\n\n";

my $W = 'ABC';
my $N = '002';

while ( my $record = <DATA> ) {
    if ( $record =~ /\[$W-$N\].*first=(.*?)\n/s ) {
        print "first='$1'\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
[ABC-001]
first=firstabc001
phone=sometext
last=sometext

[DEF-001]
phone=sometext
last=sometext
first=firstdef001

[ABC-102]
phone=sometext
first=firstabc002
last=sometext

[GHI-001]
first=firstghi001
phone=sometext
last=sometext
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk -F= -v W='ABC' -v N='002' '$0 == "[" W "-" N "]"{p=1}
   p && $1 == "first"{print $2; p=0}' file
```

**Output:**

```
firstabc002
```